# How to use freopen to read print streams from Shader?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I am using this command in C++ as i am starting without console to direct the outputs to the Console Window. I would like to direct shader-errors as well to this console.

What parameters do i need to accomplish it? Or is there a FILE Datatypes i can read?

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin); 
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout); 
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Shader Compilation errors are reported through `glGetShaderInfoLog`. It's your responsibility to fetch the logs from OpenGL and write them to the stdio file stream. Something like this

```
GLint shader_status;
glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shader_status);
if( shader_status == GL_FALSE ) {
    GLint log_length, returned_length;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);

    char *shader_infolog = calloc(log_length);
    if(!shader_infolog) {
        goto alloc_infolog_failed;
    }

    glGetShaderInfoLog(
        shader,
        log_length,
        &returned_length,
        shader_infolog);
    fputs("Shader compilation failed:\n", stderr);
    fwrite(shader_infolog, returned_length, 1, stderr);
    fputc('\n', stderr);

    free(shader_infolog);
    goto failed_compile;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it doesn't sound convenient, but it's a solution. When creating a console application, normally opengl is directing the outputs to that console? or isn't that per se?

Comment: @user1767754: OpenGL doesn't know what a "console" is. Nothing is directed to the console by OpenGL. This is completely your responsibility, just like any other OpenGL errors must be fetched and reported by your program.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try your code in a while and adjust it for my purposes.